# Charge to Mass ratio of Ion thruster

Tags: propulsion, ion-thruster

For an Ion thruster which emits single charged ions, the charge to mass ratio is find out by considering the charge( whether it is positive or negative) and the mass of that ion.when the ion thruster is a bipolar type which emits positive and negative ions at a time, how can we calculate charge to mass ratio of that system

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio#Zeeman_Effect